# What counts as boiling on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul

I'm relatively new to making cholent. Before Shabbat starts I turn the temp down to around the warm area on the slow cooker. What I hadn't considered is whether it would boil or not. What happens is that most of the time it's still, but from time to time starts bubbling for a bit and stops.

My question is what counts as boiling on Shabbat? How do I stop this from happening if it counts as boiling?

Comment: As I understand it, the "boiling" per se is not the concern, it's "cooking". All rulles that I have read (have to locate a link to source) state that before Shabbat, the chulent must already be "cooked" meaning that it must be minimally edible, i.e. - no raw meat or hard inedible beans.

Comment: If there's a source you can find on that, it would be greatly appreciated. I know the cholent is supposed to be edible before Shabbat begins, but whether boiling is fine afterwards, I'm not sure about.

Comment: I see you got the answer, already, with source. In summary, it is cooking, not specifically boiling meaning "bubbles".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prohibition of *bishul* on Shabbos is cooking which means taking an uncooked item and making it cooked. This process of cooking begins when the food's temperature is brought up to *yad soledes bo* - enough for one's hand to recoil, somewhere between 110-160 degrees Fahrenheit. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yad_soledet_bo), see Mishne Berurah 318:23)

There is no prohibition for an item to boil on Shabbos (or to move a fully cooked hot item on the *blech* closer to the fire causing it to boil). When the Shulchan Aruch uses the term *rosachas* often understood as boiling (see 451), in the context of cooking on Shabbos it means *yad soledes bo*. (Mishne Berurah, ibid)